# pip3 doesn't work when installing anything and throw pip require TLS/SSL, ssl Python not available

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pip, ubuntu-16.04

i am trying to install somme modules in my python3.8 env in my online server(ubuntu 16.04). the probleme is, i can't install anything because pip3 give me the same error everytime i tried to install

error1:

`WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting asgiref==3.2.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/asgiref/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/asgiref/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/asgiref/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/asgiref/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/asgiref/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/asgiref/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/asgiref/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement asgiref==3.2.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for asgiref==3.2.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping`

i tried to see if my pip have some problems so i tried this:

```
(env) user:~/test/djangoallauth# pip3 -V
pip 19.2.3 from /root/test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

and the without the evn it gives me this:

error2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ImportError: cannot import name 'DependencyWarning'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ImportError: cannot import name 'DependencyWarning'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 145, in apport_excepthook
    os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL, 0o640), 'wb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/crash/_usr_bin_pip3.0.crash'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ImportError: cannot import name 'DependencyWarning'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ImportError: cannot import name 'DependencyWarning'
```

i tried to reinstall requests but couldn't for the same error2
i installed ssl but the pip doesn't reconginze it or something.

i am not very familliar with python and pip so I may have missed something trivial but i don't see it, if someone can help me i would appreciate it very much thank you.

Comment: how did you build python? sounds like the `ssl` module failed to build

Comment: i don't know what you mean, but i installed python like this:
`sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.2/Python-3.8.2.tgz
sudo tar xzf Python-3.8.2.tgz
cd Python-3.8.2
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall`

Comment: you were probably missing `libssl-dev` while building -- you might find installing python3.8 from a ppa (where it's compiled with all of the proper modules) a better choice -- I maintain deadsnakes which is one option there https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa